# Problems installing kint correctly

Tags: php, kint

I downloaded *kint*, unzipped it and moved the folder to the Library folder.  Then I put this code as the second line of my PHP file (after

```
require '/kint/Kint.class.php';
```

and now, when I go to execute the PHP code, I get a blank screen.

Was putting it in the Library folder the wrong place to put it?  (the instructions say put it "somewhere comfy"... what kind of installation instruction is that?)

Comment: Your require path doesn't include the Library folder. Are you using a class autoloader?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of... all I did was download it, unzip it and move it to the Library folder.  In OS X, which folder would automatically be in the Path?  (i.e. user/local/bin?)

Comment: Just look at `var_dump(is_file('/kint/Kint.class.php'));` and you'll see, that the file does not actually exist. You can use the magic constant `__DIR__` to get the directory of the current file and then locate Kint relatively - for example `require __DIR__ . '../Library/kint/Kint.class.php';` or something. I'm sorry, you'll just have to learn basic file inclusion in PHP, I can't help you further - by saying "put it somewhere comfy" I am assuming the end user is capable of that, lets agree, simple, skill.

Comment: I guess I should have said I'm a PHP noob... thanks for the help, tho', I really appreciate it.  Hopefully that will get me working with Kint.  :D